# Read text file with lots of line in C#

Tags: c#, .net, io, streamreader, readline

I have a text file, that could potentially have up to 1 Million lines in it, and I have a code for reading the file one line at a time, but this is taking a lot of time...lots and lots of time. Is there a method in c# to potentially optimize this process, and improve the reading. This is the code I'm using.

```
using(var file = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         //do something.
     }
}
```

Any suggestions on reading these lines in bulk or improving the process?

Thanks.

Thanks for all your comments. The issue had to do with the \do something where I was using the SmartXls library to write to Excel, which was causing the bottle neck. I have contacted the developers to address the issue. All the suggested solutions will work in other scenarios.

Comment: How large is the file?  You may be limited in disk I/O speed.  That's not really a programming problem.  If anything might need to be optimized it could be the mystery code in your `// do something.` snippet.

Answer (score 6):

Well, this code would be simpler, if you're using .NET 4 or later you can use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readlines.aspx):

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines())
{
    // Do something
}
```

Note that this is *not* the same as [`ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx), as `ReadLines` returns an `IEnumerable<string>` which reads lines lazily, instead of reading the whole file in one go.

The effect at execution time will be broadly the same as your original code (it won't improve performance) - this is just simpler to read.

Fundamentally, if you're reading a large file, that can take a long time - but reading just a million lines shouldn't take "lots and lots of time". My guess is that whatever you're *doing* with the lines takes a long time. You might want to parallelize that, potentially using a producer/consumer queue (e.g. via [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx)) or [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx), or just use Parallel LINQ, `Parallel.ForEach` etc.

You should use a profiler to work out where the time is being spent. If you're reading from a very slow file system, then it's possible that it really *is* the reading which is taking the time. We don't have enough information to guide you on that, but you should be able to narrow it down yourself.

Comment: But the OP asked about improving performance. And this code and his have the same performance.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM: As I said in the answer - this is about improving readability, but it will have the same effect. I'll amplify that in the answer.

Comment: I think by `improve the reading` he meant the reading of the file not the code.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM: Well, it said "improving the process" - I'd say this is still an improvement. See the edit though, which *does* talk about performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more data at once using StreamReader's `int ReadBlock(char[] buffer, int index, int count)` rather than line by line.  This avoids reading reading the entire file at once (`File.ReadAllLines`) but allows you to process larger chunks in RAM at a time.

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance, consider performing whatever work you are currently doing in your loop by spawning another thread to handle the load.

```
Parallel.ForEach(file.ReadLines(), (line) =>
{
   // do your business
});
```

Comment: Using `Parallel.ForEach` is much easier to code and will do a much better job of thread management.  It will be able to intelligently determine the appropriate number of concurrent threads, and it will effectively ensure that that number isn't exceeded, unlike your code that constantly spins down every time it hits the cap instead of just sitting there right at the cap.

Comment: Thanks, Servy, I didn't know about the Parallel.ForEach method.

Comment: Also, this assumes that the work can be done in parallel, and done in parallel safely.  We don't know if that's the case, or if the work is expensive enough to justify parallelizing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use streamreader, see if it's faster

```
string filePath = "";
string fileData = "";
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
                byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                fs.Read(data, 0, int.Parse(fs.Length.ToString()));
                fileData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If space is not an issue..Create a buffer of around 1mb..

```
using(BufferedStream bs=new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(path),1024*1024))
{
     int read=-1;
     byte[] buffer=new byte[1024*1024];
     while((read=bs.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length))!=0)
     {
            //play with buffer
     }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use `ReadAllLines(filepath)` and load the file into an array of lines, like this: 
`string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"path");`

Comment: You shouldn't be pulling that much data into memory all at the same time.